# How Compare two columns of Same SQL table to find duplicate records

Tags: duplication

I have one table with two columns:

```
StartDateTime
EndDateTime
```

What will be best query to find out which rows has same (StartDateTime, EndDateTime)?

Comment: Please consider reading [this post](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (a table in a relational database is always a "SQL table"). Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify a particular RDBMS (SQL Server, Oracle, etc.), but here is a quick solution that would probably work on most.

Assuming your table has some kind of unique key (primary key - like `ID`) to determine the difference between one row and another row, you could use a correlated exists check.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM table1 a
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM table1
        WHERE StartDateTime = a.StartDateTime
            AND EndDateTime = a.EndDateTime
            AND Id <> a.Id
        )
```